# OpenCV detecting a single symbol with multiple bounding boxes

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am using OpenCV to put bounding boxes on handwritten math equation inputs. Currently, my code sometimes places multiple smaller bounding boxes around different parts of a singular image instead of creating one large box around the image. I'm not sure why this is happening. My current code to filter the image and find the contours to draw the bounding box is as follows:

```
    img = cv2.imread(imgpath)

    morph = img.copy()
    morph = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 1))
    morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 15))

    # take morphological gradient
    gradient_image = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(gradient_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    img_grey = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    blur = cv2.medianBlur(img_grey,3)


    ret, thing = cv2.threshold(blur, 0.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    img_dilation = cv2.dilate(thing, kernel, iterations=3)


    conturs_lst = cv2.findContours(img_dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
```

An example of the actual result is as follows:

[image]

OG Image:

[image]

Comment: For some reason, increasing the kernal size made it worse..

Comment: Can you add your original image?

Comment: Just added it to the post!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right idea but I think you're overusing `cv2.morphologyEx` to continuously erode and dilate the image. You mention your problem:

> Currently, my code sometimes places multiple smaller bounding boxes around different parts of a singular image instead of creating one large box around the image.

When you use `cv2.findContours`, its working correctly but since your contours are actually blobs instead of one interconnected singular image, it creates multiple bounding boxes. To remedy this problem, you can dilate the image to connect the blobs together.

I've rewrote your code without the extra `cv2.morphologyEx` repetitions. The main idea is as follows:

- Convert the image into grayscale
- Blur image
- Threshold image to separate background from desired object
- Dilate image to connect blobs to form a singular image
- Find contours and filter contours using threshold min/max area

Threshold image to isolate desired sections. Note some of the contours have broken connections. To fix this, we dilate the image to connect the blobs.

[image]

Dilate image to form singular objects. Now note we have the unwanted horizontal section at the bottom, we can find contours and then filter using area to remove that section.

[image]

Results

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

original_image = cv2.imread("1.jpg")
image = original_image.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 160, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel , iterations=4)

cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("dilate", dilate)

# Find contours in the image
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

contours = []

threshold_min_area = 400
threshold_max_area = 3000

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > threshold_min_area and area < threshold_max_area:
        # cv2.drawContours(original_image,[c], 0, (0,255,0), 3)
        cv2.rectangle(original_image, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (0,255,0),1)
        contours.append(c)

cv2.imshow("detected", original_image) 
print('contours detected: {}'.format(len(contours)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Hm, that seems to do the trick, however, I think some of the stuff I added was to allow it to also detect "=" symbols as one bounding box. Not sure how to add that into this implementation. Could I just increase the kernal dimensions?

Comment: You can experiment with kernel dimensions and also try to merge it together into one bounding box by detecting close connected components

Comment: Ah ok thanks! Besides that everything looks fine, however it seems sometimes im getting that large unwanted horizontal section in some of my other pictures and it is actually coverin?g some of the symbols i'm looking to detect. What is the reason for that showing up

Comment: One of the preprocessing steps is `cv2.threshold` which helps classify the pixel value. Depending on the lighting on different images, this value may cover more or less so you might have to change this value. Currently this global value is set at 160 and will probably be different for various images. For a dynamic approach, you can look into [`cv2.adaptiveThreshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html) which is probably better in conditions where the image has different lighting conditions in different areas.